# SharedPreference updating information

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreference to keep track of a character used, points that character brings and the number of characters that the user has and the last two are concatenated in a string which I append split in order to get one of the values (and append them again later). However, I'm not really sure that the way I'm trying to go about updating my data is how it should be done. I would really appreciate to hear some opinions.
Here is the code where I save the Shared Preference:

```
    SharedPreferences aSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Aprefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int[] aData = new int[2];
    aData[0] = 3;
    aData[1] = 0;
    StringBuilder strA = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
        strA.append(aData[i]).append(",");
    }
    aSharedPref.edit().putString("A", strA.toString());
    aSharedPref.edit().apply();`
```

and where I retrieve it to update it:

```
    SharedPreferences aSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(Aprefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dataA = aSharedPref.getString("A", "");
    StringTokenizer stA = new StringTokenizer(dataA, ",");
    int[] listA = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        listA[i] = Integer.parseInt(stA.nextToken());
    }
    listA[1] = listA[1] + 1;
    StringBuilder strA = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
        strA.append(listA[i]).append(",");
    }
    aSharedPref.edit().putString("A", strA.toString());
    aSharedPref.edit().apply();
```

Also one more question regarding apply() and commit(), from what I gathered commit writes the data to persistent storage immediately while apply handles it in the background. So would it matter which one I use when saving data which I plan to update throughout the app.

Comment: You sure you want to use the SharedPref like this? It's more meant to keep track of data which should persist from one sessions to another. With that in mind you should use static field or anything similar to keep track on your data and then only save it if the app is about to get shut down. Btw `getDefaultSharedPreferences` is not the same as `getSharedPreferences`.

Comment: Well I tried using SQLite instead but to be honest it really confused me a lot so I switched to SharedPref and since I won't be saving lots of data in this way thought it might be good enough, I'm really not sure though ... Is the constant editing of data likely to corrupt it or result in miscalculations in your opinion?